# How to respond to maliciously spoofed site?

Tags: legal, webserver, malware, isp

I recently stumbled into a spoofed version of StackOverflow and reported it to Google, SO and posted this question on [SO Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308546/i-found-a-forged-version-of-stackoverflow).

*Almost two weeks later* that offending site is still up and serving awful pop-up adds linked to page events.  For example if you scroll down the page a  *casino* is advertised.  You can read in SOmeta there is a **phishing attack** too, so be careful if you navigate there.

(It seems SO, in personal email to me, and SO users are content in classifying  with this as a copyright issue)

But if my commercial sites were spoofed especially to this detail, I would want them *shut down immediately*!  Particularly if malicious content is being served like those fake virus reports asking for personal contact ... these are blatent attempts in fraud on my users!

It's a really broad question, but as a Webmaster what can be done to shut down such sites?

**Can the domain name register be involved or forced to pull the plug?**

*or their web server service if they have one or if they are serving from a physical server their internet service provider?*

The question is similar to [Malicious copy of site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78834/malicious-copy-of-site), but with **criminal intent**!

Does any Webmaster have **experience** with this, if this happens to me, what evidence has to be collected and who should I go to?

*This question is similar to the question above, but not a duplicate.  I expect there should be additional actions to take to stop illegal phishing attempts (fraud) that the site is being used for.  Additionally the two answers are superficial and don't provide further information to answer my question of how to shut down illicit activity.*

Comment: This is serious and I am a bit surprised that the SO meta site did not see it as a critical issue. Still, the first linked answer did point to a form on the bottom of each SO page for reporting issues that require attention. It seems that this question makes your point better than the SO meta question. I do not think they got it. But you are very clear here. Have you tried the form?? You can, I assume, link to this Q as well as the SO meta Q.

Comment: Technically, this question would be off-topic here since it is not about a site you control, however, I do appreciate your trying so hard to reach out and get a problem solved because you care about the community. This is one reason why I up-voted the question and hope others will agree. I am not sure what to recommend. But some of the more senior users may have an idea.